# Connected components of an open subset

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, connectedness, dimension-theory-algebra

Suppose we have an (affine) irreducible algebraic variety $X$ over $\mathbb{R}$, and we are given one polynomial $f$. Consider the closed subset $C$ where this is zero. What can we say about the number of connected components of $X \setminus C$ with respect to the Euclidean topology? What are essential data about $f$ to look at?

I have heard about a proof of the Jordan-curve theorem that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus Y$,  with $Y \sim S^1$ via a differentiable map, has exactly two connected components, which use cohomological tools; any insight about a connection between my question and cohomology of something?

Thank you,
Andrea

Comment: Do you mean the number of connected component for the Zariski topology ? Then $X$ would be connected : in an irreducible space, every open subset is connected (this is the definition of irreducible). Or did you want the analytic topology ?

Comment: You are right. No, I mean analytic connected components, just in the case of R^2\S^1.

Comment: I changed the hypotheses to be clearer and to focus on my problem, which turned to be a litlle more specific ($C$ has codimension 1).

Comment: So you mean the set of connected component of $(X\setminus C)(\mathbb{R})$. I don't think there is an easy answer to that question. For example, if $X=\mathbb{A}^2$ and $C$ is an elliptic curve, then there might be 2 or 3 connected components depending on the discriminant. But I'll be interested if there is something to say...

Comment: In my case I have a projection of Y to X, where Y is a product of U(n_k)'s  and GL(m_j, C)'s, and the map is the projection on GL(m_j)'s factors. I am not sure if GL(m_j)'s must be replaced by U(m_j)'s. The closed C is the projection of a closed subset f_1*...*f_r=0 (and r is big). It would be interesting for me to understand even just if X\setminus C is connected or not.